# how do i put my strpos result in my array?

Tags: php, strpos

> Hi i have a little problem, i want to filter $array to get only music
>   ! but when i run it , it displays everything in my folder include .jpg
>   ,.. and . sorry if i'm not clear , English is not my native language.
>   Thanks

```
$repertoire = "Classic";
    $array = scandir($repertoire);
    $arraymp3 = array();


    foreach ($array as $element) {
        if (strpos($element, '.mp3'));{
            $arraymp3[] = $element;             
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) Your if statement does this: `;` If it is true. 2) You probably want to check for `!== FALSE` with your `strpos()`

Comment: First of all, there shouldn't be a `;` after the if statement. Also, the condition in the if statement should be `if (strpos($element, '.mp3') !== FALSE)`.

Comment: Thanks! it worked! love you <3

Answer (score 0):

You will try like this

```
foreach ($array as $element) {

    $ismp3String = strpos($element, '.mp3')
    if ($ismp3String !== false){
        $arraymp3[] = $element;             
    }
}
```

For more details you will read http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php this carefully how it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function.

```
$arraymp3 = glob("*.mp3");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $pieces = explode(".", $element);
    $al = sizeof($pieces);
    if ($pieces[$al-1] == ".mp3") {
$arraymp3[] = $element;
}
```

Try the above code instead =]